# Eclipse encode project to ANSI cause weird characters cannot be read on linux

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

i code some plugins (java) for bukkit (minecraft) but i'm having some issues like "unacceptable character 'ï¿½' (0xFFFD)" when the server tries to read the config files, in windows works perfect, in linux no... i need to use ANSI cause i and some users need the special characters, but even not adding them to the config when trying to run it on linux i get this. I tried to encode to ANSI but i get the same error. Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are already encoding to ANSI, and you just need to read them in on the Java side as ANSI (Windows-1252) as well.

Comment: ANSI is the default Java encoding on Windows systems. UTF-8 is the default encoding on (many) Linux systems. Either transcode the files from whichever ANSI encoding you're using to UTF-8 or find a way to pass the correct file encoding to the build tool.

Comment: Tried in utf-8 also but get same error, i encoded the files into ISO-8859-1 and i'm getting no error but if i try to add any special character as "áéíñ.. etc" i get the errors back :/

Comment: Encode your files in UTF-8. Encode everything in UTF-8. UTF-8 all the way. UTF-8 is an unicode encoding, unicode supports all the characters ISO-8859-1/ANSI supports plus literally 100 000 more characters.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Linux contains two different type of default encoding 
for windows it is UTF16 and for Linux it is UTF8 so might be creating the problem while reading or creates the junck characters

while reading or writing file pass the UTF format in which file it to be read / write

for example

```
writeData(String Data,UTFfromate);


WriteData("Test","UTF-8");


readData(String Data,UTFfromate);


readData("Test","UTF-8");
```

Comment: The problem is: it's a plugin, a bukkit plugin, my code doesn't load the files, bukkit yaml parser does and cause it's linux it gets this error, i don't know how to encode propperly the files to avoid this..